# Nginx no error page is showing, no matter what configuration I use

Tags: php, azure, docker, nginx, configuration

I'm trying to configure an error page in nginx for 500 and 502 error codes, I tried many different configuration options and solutions but none of them worked for me.

The issue itself is, that no matter how I do the configuration, I always get the generic Nginx error page with 502 bad gateway.

The following docker stack is running with these containers:

- Nginx
- MySQL
- Composer
- Azure CLI
- PHP

A TYPO3 system is running behind the php/composer container.

I'm using Nginx instead of a Apache web server.
Below you can see my current nginx configuration.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html/public;

    index index.php index.htm index.html;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name _;

    # Disable sendfile as per https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/virtualbox.html
    sendfile off;
    error_log /dev/stdout info;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    # NGINX - Provide error page
    error_page 500 502 /error.html;
    location = /error.html {
        internal;
    }

    ## provide a health check endpoint
    location /healthcheck {
        access_log off;
        stub_status     on;
        keepalive_timeout 0;    # Disable HTTP keepalive
        return 200;
    }

    location / {
        absolute_redirect off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on socket
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass ${PHP_DOMAIN}:9000;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 128k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        # fastcgi_read_timeout should match max_execution_time in php.ini
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $http_x_blackfire_query;
    }

    # Expire rules for static content
    # Feed
    location ~* \.(?:rss|atom)$ {
        expires 1h;
    }

    # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
        expires 1M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Prevent clients from accessing hidden files (starting with a dot)
    # This is particularly important if you store .htpasswd files in the site hierarchy
    # Access to `/.well-known/` is allowed.
    # https://www.mnot.net/blog/2010/04/07/well-known
    # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5785
    location ~* /\.(?!well-known\/) {
        deny all;
    }

    # Prevent clients from accessing to backup/config/source files
    location ~* (?:\.(?:bak|conf|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|psd|sh|sql|sw[op])|~)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to composer files
    location ~* composer\.(?:json|lock) {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to flexform files
    location ~* flexform[^.]*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to language files
    location ~* locallang[^.]*\.(?:xml|xlf)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to static typoscript files
    location ~* ext_conf_template\.txt|ext_typoscript_constants\.(?:txt|typoscript)|ext_typoscript_setup\.(?:txt|typoscript) {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to miscellaneous protected files
    location ~* /.*\.(?:bak|co?nf|cfg|ya?ml|ts|typoscript|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|sh|sql)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to recycler and temporary directories
    location ~ _(?:recycler|temp)_/ {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to configuration files stored in fileadmin
    location ~ fileadmin/(?:templates)/.*\.(?:txt|ts|typoscript)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to libaries, source and temporary compiled data
    location ~ ^(?:vendor|typo3_src|typo3temp/var) {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to protected extension directories
    location ~ (?:typo3conf/ext|typo3/sysext|typo3/ext)/[^/]+/(?:Configuration|Resources/Private|Tests?|Documentation|docs?)/ {
        deny all;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ /$1.$3 last;
    }

    #Include development locations if needed
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/locations/*.conf;
}
```

I think the issue itself does not come from the configuration but from anywhere else but I don't know where.. I can't find the problem.

Hope u guys can help me, btw it's my first stack overflow question :D

EDIT:

Just added the configuration below to test the error codes but unfortunately I still get a 502 Bad Gateway, maybe a problem with the local setup. To my surprise the configured location for a healthcheck is working, just the error page not.

```
location /get_error {
        return 500;
    }
```

UPDATE:

The configuration itself was correct, I just deployed the changes made to the dev system and it just worked! I don't know why and where the issue was but it just won't work for my local dev environment.

Comment: 502 is bad gateway, 504 is gateway timeout. Are you hooking the correct error code?

Comment: Yes it should be the correct ones, sometimes the typo3 crashes unexpected and crashes the php process too, until we find the problem there we want to handle this with a nginx error page. @RichardSmith